# Error al enviar formulario dinámico que esta dentro de un while porque solo envía datos del primer registro

Tags: php, html, jquery

estoy intentando de enviar un formulario que esta dentro de un while pero nome funciona porque siempre envia el primero no importa cual seleccione.
este es el codigo while donde se llena el form dinamicamente con distintos registros de la base de datos

```
<tr>
                <th width="70px">N° Factura</th>
                <th width="150px">Proveedor</th>
                <th width="60px">Valor</th>
                <th width="170px">Usuario</th>
                <th width="50px">Estado</th>
                <th width="40px">Opción</th>
            </tr>

    <?php $cont=0;   while ($row = $rFacturasP->fetch_object()) { ?>
        
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->entNroFactura; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row->nameProveedor; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo number_format($row->entTotal); ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $row->nameUser." ".$row->apeUser; ?></td>
                <td ><?php echo $row->estadoDescripcion; ?></td>
                <td >
                
            <form method="POST" action="index.php?pg=PagarFacturaPendiente" id="frmPagarFacturaPendiente<?php echo $cont;?>">
                <input type="text" name="Nconsigna" placeholder="Número Consignación">
                <input type="text" name="factura" value="<?php echo ($row->entNroFactura);?>" >
                <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo ($id_user);?>">
                <input type="button" id="pagarFacturaP" name="" value="Pagar" >
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
            
                <?php echo $cont+=1; } ?>
```

estoy tratando de colocarle nombre diferente al formulario colocandole un contador  para saber a cual estoy enviando pero nose como hacer que se envie el formulario al que le hago click
lo estube realizando con la etiqueta  y funciona bien el problema es que tengo que capturar un campo que el usuario debe llenar

```
<a href="index.php?pg=PagarFacturaPendiente&factura=<?php echo base64_encode($row->entNroFactura)?>&user=<?php echo base64_encode($id_user)?>" </a>
```

Comment: Mírate bien esta respuesta a ver si te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510745/como-diferenciar-id-en-listado/510752#510752

Comment: El problema aquí es que no estás creando UN formulario, sino `N` formularios, donde `N` será la cantidad de elementos del `while`. Me pregunto si realmente necesitas un formulario en este contexto ¿? Lamentablemente tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Podrías explicar con más claridad qué es lo que quieres mandar exactamente? Quizá es una mejor solución construir un enlace con cada elemento, poniendo en ese enlace el dato o los datos que quieres pasar. Los formularios suelen usarse para enviar un conjunto de datos, como por ejemplo todos los datos de una persona: Nombre, Apellido, Dirección.

Comment: hola @A. Cedano gracias por responder, es cierto yo había colocado un enlace con los datos que necesitaba pero me urge que adicional a esos datos el cliente ingrese otro dato adicional y no se como capturarlo con el enlace

Comment: @manterguru gracias por responder voy a intentar realizarlo de esa forma a ver que sucede

Comment: Esto se puede hacer de diferentes formas y depende del contexto. Por ejemplo, si se trata de un grupo de datos unitarios, lo propio sería un formulario (por ejemplo, si se tratase de recoger los datos de una persona). Ahora bien, si se tratase de datos repetitivos (tipo fila), puedes crear por cada fila los `N` inputs que necesites para recoger datos y poner un botón al lado de cada fila, de modo que al hacer click sobre ese botón se manden los datos de ESA fila. Esto es muy simple de hacer mediante Javascript y usando Ajax o la nueva API Fetch para mandar los datos al servidor.

Comment: después de tanto analizar, lo que realice fue lo siguiente en la etiqueta <a> cree un evento onclick que envía los datos a un archivo query y este muestra un formulario para diligenciar y enviar

Answer (score 0):

después de tanto analizar, lo que realice fue lo siguiente en la etiqueta `<a>` cree un evento onclick que envía los datos a un archivo query y este muestra un formulario para diligenciar y enviar

```
<?php $cont=0;   while ($row = $rFacturasP->fetch_object()) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->entNroFactura; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row->nameProveedor; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo number_format($row->entTotal); ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row->nameUser." ".$row->apeUser; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row->estadoDescripcion; ?></td>
            <td >
            
        <a onclick="abrirForm('<?php echo ($row->entNroFactura);?>',
                              '<?php echo ($id_user);?>')">Ver 
          </a>
    </td>
    </tr>'
```

y en archivo jquery

```
function abrirForm(factura,iduser){
  $("#txtFactura").val(factura);
  $("#txtUser").val(iduser);
 $("#frm").dialog({
      width : 'auto',
      height : 'auto',
      modal : true,
      show : "blind",
      hide : "slideUp",
      dragable : true
     });
}
```

y el form html es

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?pg=PagarFacturaPendiente" id="frm">
     <input type="text" name="Nconsigna" placeholder="Número Consignación">
     <input type="hidden" name="factura" value="<?php echo ($row->entNroFactura);?>" id="txtFactura" >
     <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo ($id_user);?>" id="txtUser">
     <input type="button" id="pagarFacturaP" name="" value="Pagar" >
</form>
```

con esto puedo obtener lo que quiero, pero tengo un inconveniente que si la variable lleva un caracter comillas " dentro no me abre el formulario. ¿Como puede hacer para pasar caracteres espaciales?