# Obtener el valor de un input dentro de un bucle for

Tags: javascript, html, python, web, flask

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de inventario con *Python* y *Flask* en la cual el stock es modificable con input.

El tema es que cuando presiono el botón para editar siempre toma el primer valor. ¿De qué forma puedo hacer que obtenga el valor correspondiente al input ingresado y botón pulsado?

```
<tbody>
  {% for fruit, stock in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ fruit.fruit }}</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="{{stock.kilo}}" name="kilo" class="kilo text-center bg-dark text-white" id="kilo" placeholder="{{stock.kilo}}"></td>
    <td>{{ stock.center }}</td>
    <td>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary editbtn"
        onclick="edit_stock({{stock.id}})"
      >
        Editar
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-danger"
        onclick="delete_stock({{ stock.id}})"
      >
        Borrar
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>

function edit_stock(stock_id) {
  kilo = $('#kilo').val();
  alert(kilo)
  if (kilo <= 0){
    alert("Ha ingresado una cantidad incorrecta de Kilos");
  } else {
    if (confirm("¿Quieres modificar el registro?") == true) {
      $("#id_stock").val(stock_id);
      $("#kilos").val(kilo);
      $("#edit").attr("action", "edit_stock").submit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Estas repitiendo el id, por lo tanto solo te cogerá el primero. Mírate la explicación de esta respuesta a ver si te ayuda a entenderlo:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510745/como-diferenciar-id-en-listado/510752#510752

Answer (score 0):

probaste con algo así...
Claramente cada id debe ser diferente.
Quedo atenta para ver el resultado!

```
<td>{{ fruit.fruit }}</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="{{stock.id}}" value="{{stock.kilo}}" name="kilo" class="kilo text-center bg-dark text-white" id="kilo" placeholder="{{stock.kilo}}"></td>
    <td>{{ stock.center }}</td>
    <td>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary editbtn"
        onclick="edit_stock({{stock.id}})"
      >
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.