# Editar registro de una tabla SQL

Tags: modal

Tengo una tabla con datos de la base de datos. En la última columna, hay una imagen que hace referencia a la EDICIÓN de ese usuario.
Mi idea es que al hacer click, se abra una ventana modal con los datos del usuario seleccionado en la tabla.
Mis códigos:

**Código de la opción EDITAR:**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_usuario_edicion">
    <img id="img_editar" src="../imagenes/editar.png" name="editar_usuario" onclick="usuario_editar('<?php echo $usuarios ['id_usuario'] ?>')">
</a>
```

**Código del modal que se abre:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_usuario_edicion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Función:**

```
function usuario_editar(id_editar) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../head_menu/usuarios_edicion.php',
    data: {
      id: id_editar
    },
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('#modal_usuario_edicion .modal-body').html(data);
  });
}
```

He podido lograr el objetivo, pero está bien? Ahora debo corregir el error de que siempre me muestre el último usuario de la tabla.

Comment: A no ser que el contenido del modal lo estés cargando por AJAX me temo que lo estás planteando mal. Al hacer un include haces que el servidor devuelva un html ya renderizado

Comment: @CésarGonzález Totalmente así es César. Tengo un archivo con todo el diseño de la página para la edición del usuario y que quería "incluir" en ese modal. Obviamente si lo dejo asi se ve perfecto pero no carga los datos de la tabla. No estoy usando AJAX. Deberé amigarme jaja

Comment: Lo que dices del último usuario de la tabla suena a [este problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510745/como-diferenciar-id-en-listado/510752#510752), o que tu  `$usuarios ['id_usuario']` lo estas sobreescribiendo en un bucle y es como los immortales, solo puede quedar uno, y es el correspondiente al último ciclo de tu bucle

Comment: @masterguru Lo solucioné recargando la página con location.reload(); y funciona a la perfección de acuerdo al usuario seleccionado, es decir, cuando el usuario acepta o cancela, se recarga y ahí es donde al volver a seleccionar no toma el mismo usuario. Aviso, el modal no puede cerrarse si no es aceptando o cancelando. ¿Está mal? Vi tu enlace y solo quería el ID. Gracias!

Comment: No se si acabo de entender lo que has hecho ni lo que has podido aprovechar de mi enlace, si es que te ha servido de algo.  Ahora que me fijo un poco mejor, me parece ver que tienes un espacio entre `$usuarios` y `['id_usuario']` cuando tiene que ir todo junto así:  `$usuarios['id_usuario']`.  Lo del location reload no lo veo claro, la verdad, pues entonces el ajax no sirve para nada

Comment: Ajax es quien mi carga la página en el modal con el ID del usuario seleccionado. Sobre lo de $usuarios y ['id_usuario'] todo junto, me estoy fijando y en todas las páginas lo tengo separado, respetando comillas y funciona perfecto, tanto al mostrarme datos en la tabla como al cargar en la base de datos. Quiero que sepas que soy novato, aprendo de todo lo que ustedes me van corrigiendo. Antes no me animaba a ajax jajaja

Comment: Vale, perdona, es que estoy espeso... ahora te he leido mejor. Lo del modal es normal, pero aparte de los botones deberia poderse cerrar con la crucecita de arriba a la derecha, si tiene y esta bien codificada. Seria como un cancelar. Eso de la separación, pues nada, si te funciona y tienes miles por arreglar no lo cambies, aunque la sintaxis formal y correcta es todo junto.

Comment: Obvio, desde ahora todo junto, el resto lo iré de a poco actualizando. Te agradezco esa observación, tal vez ahora no me da error, pero más adelante sí. Y al modal no le puse la crucecita arriba, solo los botones. Igual es una página de uso interno, no tiene acceso "al mundo" jaja Gracias por tu ayuda y consejos. Valen mucho.

Comment: Vale, bueno, pues espera que te paso mi cuenta de bitcoin y sirvete pasar por caja :-)

Comment: @masterguru jajajajajaja en Argentina solo tenemos pesos y no valen nadaaaaaaaaa